# Undefined symbol: apr_memcache_add_server

Tags: linux, fedora, httpd, mod-auth

I installed `httpd-devel` through yum and after restarting `httpd` got this:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 61 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/local/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_memcache_add_server
```

This is a legacy Linux system I got in - Fedora 9, pretty old.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that's complaining is mod_dav_svn, which is used to access Subversion repositories. If you're not going to use your webserver to do that, just comment out the line where mod_dav_svn is loaded.

If you do want to use it, try installing a newer version of mod_dav_svn.